# Arduino button spams high and low even with pulldown resistor

Tags: arduino

i am trying to use a simple button for something but it keeps switching between HIGH and LOW without doing anything. pressing it also does not impact anything.

i am using a pulldown resistor but maybe i've wired it incorrectly?

[image: here is my wiring:]

and here is the code on the arduino:

```
int butnPin = 2;
int transieverPin = 4;

int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(butnPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(transieverPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(butnPin);
  delay(10);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("HIGH");
  } else {
    Serial.println("LOW");
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the button and pull-down resistor entirely. Connect a wire directly from 5V to D2. See what it outputs. Then do the same from 0V to D2. See what it outputs. This will help you diagnose if it's a hardware or software issue.

Comment: I tried it and figured out it was my breadboard doin somethin weird, guess its broken or somethin